# Given an embedded $C^k$ submanifold of $R^n$, is the distance function $C^k$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am asking because I am wondering if studying smooth manifolds is the same as studying zero loci of smooth functions with non-vanishing gradient.

Let me be a little formal for clarity:

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $i : M \to R^n$ a smooth embedding into $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Define a function $d: R^n \to R$ by $d(x) = \inf_{m \in M} d(x,m)$. Is the function $d$ smooth?

(What about if compactness is assumed? What happens if the manifold is merely immersed?)

(Edit: I did later realize that the right way to approach my underlying question for an embedding is to use the local normal form, the fact that planes are smooth varieties, and then a partition of unity to patch everything together.)

Comment: Certainly not true as stated - the distance function of the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ is not differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Well, what if we ignore a measure zero set? Can we say the distance function is smooth on $\mathbb R^n$ minus a measure zero set?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I know the distance function from a point on a Riemannian manifold is smooth almost everywhere, and I suspect the same is true for the distance function from a submanifold; but I can't find a reference. It is definitely smooth in a neighbourhood of the submanifold, so you could extend it appropriately to get a global function with the desired zero set.

Comment: @AreaMan: The distance to an embedded submanifold is non-differentiable _everywhere on the submanifold_ for precisely the same reason the absolute value is non-differentiable at the origin. This is a local matter. (That said, I'm not entirely sure of your intent: The title question doesn't match the first sentence of motivation, and doesn't appear in the question body. Further, I don't understand how the edit relates to the question....)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yeah, that is true. Euclidean distance is not the right choice of function. I guess the title to my question was not appropriate . The edit relates to the motivation in the first paragraph, which upon further reflection was the question I was really asking.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I guess the average question between my motivation and the title question is: is there a good/natural choice of function $f$ that exhibits the embedded submanifold as the zero set of $f$? (Other than pasting one together with a partition of unity.)

Comment: @AreaMan: A smooth $m$-manifold smoothly embedded in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ can _locally_ be defined as the common level set of $n - m$ real-valued functions with non-vanishing gradient, but this cannot always be done globally (e.g., a Möbius band in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$): The gradients of the local defining functions constitute a global frame of the normal bundle to $i(M)$. If $M$ is only immersed, other issues arise, e.g., an irrational-slope line on a torus. A _compact, embedded hypersurface_  in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ _is_ cut out by one function; the key step is to construct a non-vanishing normal field.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks. I don't understand why compactness is necessary. Isn't it sufficient that the embedding map is proper?

Comment: @AreaMan: Compactness isn't necessary, it's sufficient. :) Modulo details, "having trivial normal bundle" looks to be equivalent to "cut out by smooth functions with linearly independent gradients", but that doesn't seem like an answer in the spirit of your question. Regarding "properly embedded", think of a Möbius band in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ with the boundary circle removed (from the ambient space). I don't know offhand whether this type of example can arise in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ itself.